# Squaring an operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-operators

There is an excercise of squaring an operator in my book of quantun mechanics.
The operator is $$\hat{A}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}+x$$
And I should compute $\hat{A}^2$. He gives me a result 
$$\hat{A}^2=\frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+2x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}+x^2+1$$Isn't there a mistake? If I understand it correctly, there should not be that 2 before $x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$?!

Comment: The formula is correct. Why do you believe that the 2 shouldn't be there?

Comment: Because there is no reason for the 1 to be there then.

Comment: See what happens if you symbolically apply $A$ to a test function $f$. That is, $Af = f' + xf$, then $A^2f = A(f'+xf)$.

Comment: You forgot about the derivative of a product. Imagine a dummy $f$ that you apply this to.

Answer (score 5):

Apply the operator to $f(x)$. Then:
$$\hat Af=\frac {df}{dx}+xf$$

Apply the operator to $\hat Af$. Then:
\begin{align}
\hat A^2f
&=
\hat A\left(\frac {df}{dx}+xf\right)
\\
&=
\left(\frac {d }{dx}+x \right)\left(\frac {df }{dx}+xf \right)
\\
&=
\frac {d }{dx}\left(\frac {df }{dx}+xf \right)+x\left(\frac {df }{dx}+xf \right)
\\
&=
\left(\frac {d }{dx}\frac {df }{dx}+\frac {d xf}{dx} \right)+\left(x\frac {df }{dx}+x^2f \right)
\\
&=
 \frac {d^2f }{dx^2}+x\frac {d f}{dx}  +f   +x\frac {df }{dx}+x^2f 
\\
&=
 \frac {d^2f }{dx^2}+2x\frac {d f}{dx}     +x^2f +f 
\\
&=
 \left(\frac {d^2  }{dx^2}+2x\frac {d  }{dx}     +x^2  + 1 \right)f 
\end{align}
So,
$$
\boxed
{
\hat A^2 
=
\frac {d^2  }{dx^2}+2x\frac {d  }{dx}     +x^2  + 1.
}$$